# While-loop Restriction

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, restriction

I want to restrict the while Loop.

I don't want to use `break;`, instead I want to say that the loop must end after three times.

My while Loop:

```
while(!file.isFile()) { userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("UserInput);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
int i = 0;
while(!file.isFile() && i < 3) {
  userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("UserInput);
  i++;
}
```

And I agree that for loop is better choice :)

Comment: I quite like this way though; especially if you scope-block the whole thing.

Comment: @Bathsheba it's effectively just an ugly way to declare a for loop, though.

Comment: Indeed but this in many ways represents the simplest deviation to what the OP currently has.

Answer (score 3):

Use a for loop instead :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3 && !file.isFile(); i++) {
    userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("UserInput");
    ...
}
```

Comment: haha i think you win for doing the logical thing and doing for and not just answering with while :P

Comment: @natus I think that could be debated. Yes, using a for loop for counting is a more common practice; but putting "while" like conditions into a for loop on the other hand ... is not. I think many programmers that encounter a for loop  like this might overlook the second condition. Thus, in my eyes, higher potential for running into bugs. Simply because people have different expectations when they see a while loop.

Comment: @GhostCat fair call :)

Answer (score 3):

Then you need to make your while loop a for-loop like thing:

```
int counter = 0;

while (counter < 3 && !file.isFile()) { ...
  counter++;
```

For the record: the code you are showing isn't really useful: you are "overriding" the input you get from the user; and: you are condition !file.isFile() ... will not **change** its value ... because there is no code that would do that. In other words: there is more to fix about your code than just the way you are looping. It simply seems weird to ask the user the same thing three times; to ignore what he says the first two times.

Answer (score 3):

Consider refactoring to a `for` loop, introducing a counter variable in a tight scope:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3 && !file.isFile(), ++i){
    userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("UserInput"/*ToDo - quotation inserted*/);
}
```

The `for` loop conditional check `i < 3 && !file.isFile()` is verified *before* the statement in the loop body is ran.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 3;

while(!file.isFile() && i>0) { 
   userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("UserInput");
   i--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = 0;
while(!file.isFile() && count < 3 ) { 
   count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int counter = 0;
while(!file.isFile() && counter < 3) { 
   userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("UserInput);
   counter++;
}
```

Replace `3` with the number of iterations you would like the loop to be limited to.